# Sum the values if the subsequent column is "YES"

Tags: excel, sum

Lets assume there are numeric values in Column A(1:20). I want to sum so the formula is =sum(A1:A20). Now consider a case that in Column B there are values Yes and NO only.

Now I want to sum the values of Column in A if and only if the subsequent value in column B is "YES".

Comment: Explore SUMIF. (And do you mean *subsequent* or *corresponding*? Subsequent would mean in the following row.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SUMIF function to sum the values in a range that meet criteria that you specify. So :

```
=SUMIF(B1:B20, "YES", A1:A20)
```